# Python Threading: Using 2 Light Dependant Resistors (LDR)

Tags: python, multithreading

I am using a simple code from PiMyLife tutorial to read from a Light Dependant Resistor using a capacitor. This works great..
I then added a 2nd LDR and capacitor, added it to pin 31 and then duplicated the code (the rc_time function and the fuction call) to add an additional Light Dependant Resistor but for some reason the second function call never happens.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

#define the pin that goes to the circuit
pin_ldr_one = 29
pin_ldr_two = 31

def rc_time_one (pin_ldr_one):
    count_one = 0
  
    #Output on the pin for 
    GPIO.setup(pin_ldr_one, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(pin_ldr_one, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(0.1)

    #Change the pin back to input
    GPIO.setup(pin_ldr_one, GPIO.IN)
  
    #Count until the pin goes high
    while (GPIO.input(pin_ldr_one) == GPIO.LOW):
        count_one += 1

    return count_one


def rc_time_two (pin_ldr_two):
    count_two = 0
  
    #Output on the pin for 
    GPIO.setup(pin_ldr_two, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(pin_ldr_two, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(0.1)

    #Change the pin back to input
    GPIO.setup(pin_ldr_two, GPIO.IN)
  
    #Count until the pin goes high
    while (GPIO.input(pin_ldr_two) == GPIO.LOW):
        count_two += 1

    return count_two
    
#Catch when script is interrupted, cleanup correctly
try:
    # Main loop
    while True:
        print("LDR 1: ",rc_time_one(pin_ldr_one))
        print("LDR 2: ",rc_time_two(pin_ldr_two))
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
finally:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

So I thought I would try threading instead thinking that the 2 function calls were having issues.

So this is the threading code I came up with however this too fails to run the second (in this cask 2nd thread). Any ideas where I am going wrong. Thanks for all your help

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
from time import sleep, perf_counter
from threading import Thread

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

#define the pin that goes to the circuit
pin_ldr_one = 29
pin_ldr_two = 31

def rc_time_one (pin_ldr_one = 29):
    count_one = 0
  
    #Output on the pin for 
    GPIO.setup(pin_ldr_one, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(pin_ldr_one, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(0.1)

    #Change the pin back to input
    GPIO.setup(pin_ldr_one, GPIO.IN)
  
    #Count until the pin goes high
    while (GPIO.input(pin_ldr_one) == GPIO.LOW):
        count_one += 1
    print("LDR 1: ",count_one)
    return count_one


def rc_time_two (pin_ldr_two = 31):
    count_two = 0
  
    #Output on the pin for 
    GPIO.setup(pin_ldr_two, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(pin_ldr_two, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(0.1)

    #Change the pin back to input
    GPIO.setup(pin_ldr_two, GPIO.IN)
  
    #Count until the pin goes high
    while (GPIO.input(pin_ldr_two) == GPIO.LOW):
        count_two += 1
    print("LDR 2: ",count_two)
    return count_two
    
#Catch when script is interrupted, cleanup correctly
try:
    # Main loop
    while True:
        # create two new threads
        t1 = Thread(target=rc_time_one)
        t2 = Thread(target=rc_time_two)

        # start the threads
        t1.start()
        t2.start()
        t1.join()
        t2.join()
        #print("LDR 1: ",rc_time_one(pin_ldr_one))
        #print("LDR 2: ",rc_time_two(pin_ldr_two))
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
finally:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Peter

Comment: Pro tip (not an answer): Instead of duplicating the code for the second LDR, you could simply have called the same function twice, passing two different pin numbers a the function argument. Some of us call the idea _keeping it DRY._ ("DRY" stands for "Don't Repeat Yourself.") We do it because more lines of code in a project means more opportunities to make a mistake, and the more effort for some other programmer to read and understand what we did.

Comment: Tip #2: Using a busy loop to measure time can be OK if the CPU doesn't have any other work to do. Using _two_ busy loops in two separate threads though,... That invites the two threads to interfere with each other's timing. I don't know what Pi model you are using, and I wouldn't know its architecture anyway, but just as a matter of habit, I would use _ONE_ loop to monitor both GPIO pins.

Comment: When you say that the second function call never happens, How do you know that? How do you know that the GPIO pins actually ever do change from low to high?